# How to format int into a string with leading Zeros and Commas

Tags: c#, string

I need to convert an int to a string that is always 9 digits + 2 commas in length.

1 would become 000,000,001

12345 would become 000,012,345

and so on

I know I can use ToString().PadLeft(...) to add the leading zeros but don't know how to add the commas without using a few if tests. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is there really a requirement to use `ToString()`, or are you unaware of [String.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

Comment: no it doesn't have to be `ToString()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just using:

```
int myint = 12345;
string formatted = myint.ToString("000,000,000");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int number = 12345;
String result = String.Format("{0:000,000,000}", number);
```

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a custom string format, which would be simple but probably not *quite* as efficient as hand-rolled format-specific code:

```
string text = value.ToString("000,000,000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note the use of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to avoid using the current thread's culture's grouping character (and number).

One option for hand-rolling:

```
static string ToDigitsAndCommas(int value)
{
    char[] chars = new char[11];
    chars[3] = ',';
    chars[7] = ',';
    int remainder;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        value = Math.DivRem(value, 10, out remainder);
        chars[10 - i - (i / 3)] = (char) (remainder + '0');
    }
    return new string(chars);
}
```

I'd advise benchmarking this to find out whether you *really* need it rather than the simpler code though :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use a format specifier in `ToString()`:

```
var stringified = yourNumber.ToString("000,000,000");
```

And you'll get it back zero padded w commas.

Answer (score 1):

Use ToString() and specify the resulting format as an argument.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) for more infomation